# Prefix DateTime variable

Tags: cognos

I am new to cognos 10.2 report studio at the moment.
I need to declare the prefix date time in my sql in order to make my union queries works. 
I've tested a few datetime declarations but it seems not working and i keep getting the server returned an unrecognizable query framework response.

I've tried some of the codes which i found in some cognos forum as per shown in below.

```
Codes that i've tried
1. '1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000000' as invdate
2.  todate(null) as invdate
```

---

```
/********** This below is my code ***********/
select 
'fstgld' as wso,
0 as pono,
'nosh' as shpm,
'gld' as DocType,
0 as DocNo,
'gl' as item,
trim(tffst305.dim2) as ItemGroup,
tffst305.year as fy,
tffst305.perd as period,
'fst' as slsordtype,
'finbg' as finbg,
0 as Qty,
tffst305.leac as leac,
0 as Sales,
tffst305.fdah-tffst305.fcah as Cost
    current_date as invdate      <------this is the part where i keep getting error as i need to declare a prefix datetime

 From tffst305
 WHERE 
 tffst305.ptyp = 1 and
 tffst305.budg ='ACT' and
 tffst305.company_nr = 810 

 union all

 select 
cisli310.orno as wso,
cisli310.pono as pono,
cisli310.shpm as shpm,
cisli310.tran as DocType,
cisli310.idoc as DocNo,
cisli310.item as item,
tdsls411.citg as ItemGroup,
tfgld018.year as fy,
tfgld018.vprd as period,
cisli310.sotp as slsordtype,
tccom112.cfcg as finbg,
cisli310.dqua as Qty,
'inv' as leac,
cisli310.amth(1) as Sales,
0 as Cost,
    cisli305.idat as invdate  <--- extracted from the table field

 From cisli310
 RIGHT OUTER JOIN cisli305 ON cisli310.tran = cisli305.tran and 
 cisli310.idoc = cisli305.idoc
 LEFT OUTER JOIN tdsls411 ON cisli310.orno=tdsls411.orno and 
 cisli310.pono=tdsls411.pono
 LEFT OUTER JOIN tccom112 ON cisli305.ofbp = tccom112.itbp
 inner join tfgld018 on cisli310.tran = tfgld018.ttyp and cisli310.idoc = 
 tfgld018.docn 
 WHERE 

 cisli310.sotp  in ('SSP', 'SPL', 'SWK') and cisli310.amth(1) <>0 and
 cisli305.company_nr=810 and 
 cisli310.company_nr=810 and
 tdsls411.company_nr=810 and
 tfgld018.company_nr=810 and
 tccom112.company_nr=810
```

The field of the record is a datetime datatype such as 2009-07-03 03:08:03pm

Comment: You're writing raw SQL instead of using the query subjects and items provided in the package?  What RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing current_date with # timestampMask ( $current_timestamp , 'yyyy-dd-mm' ) #  You can add other date or time portions as needed

timestampMask ( string_expression1 , string_expression2 )
Returns "string_expression1", representing a timestamp with time zone, trimmed to the format specified in "string_expression2".
The format in "string_expression2" must be one of the following: 'yyyy', 'mm', 'dd', 'yyyy-mm', 'yyyymm', 'yyyy-mm-dd', 'yyyymmdd', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss+hh:mm', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.ff3', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.ff3+hh:mm', 'yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss', 'yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss+hh:mm', 'yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.ff3+hh:mm', or 'yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.ff3+hh:mm'.The macro functions that return a string representation of a timestamp with time zone show a precision of 9 digits for the fractional part of the seconds by default. The format options allow this to be trimmed down to a precision of 3 or 0.